# Происхождение слова "завять"

Tags: этимология

Интересно, а что изначально означало слово "вять" (или корень слова)? Есть слово "за-вять" и есть сленговое "от-вянь". В обоих случаях значение совершенно разное. А что же этот корень значил изначально?
Спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

И изначально то же самое - блекнуть,изнуряться, исчезать,т.е. "лишаться свежести", вялить- от него же.

http://classes.ru/all-russian/russian-dictionary-Vasmer-term-2298.htm

А сленговое, видимо, переносное ,дальше значение усугубилось. Вянуть-терять свежесть, стать липким: привял-прилип, отвянь-отлипни.